# Group functions or something like that

Tags: formatting

So basically I am writing a thesis in Latex. I want to declare a group of functions exclusive for A3 pages.

Can you guys give a tip how to declare such group? class? object? or whatever its called ?

Cheers,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? What do you have? Where are you having problems?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *group of functions*?

Comment: Do you want to create pdf files in A3 paper size?

Comment: I wish to create a group of few funtions that only affect A3 pages. Sorry I really dont know how to describe it better.

Comment: Your question is one sentence long. Be a bit more verbose, write 5 or 6 explaining what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you have some A3 pages and want to have all of them with a red background color?

Comment: How are you including the A3 pages in your document? Is the rest of your document using a different sized paper? (I'm not sure how this is done in LaTeX... I had an idea that it could not be.)